# Can foreground threads be aborted on application shutdown in C#.Net?

Tags: c#

I inherited a c# winforms app (.NET 2.0) which creates a thread upon startup in a singleton class. This thread handles messages from a messaging topic (Tibco EMS).

When the app is shutdown, the thread doesn't remain the the background? How is this possible? Is there something else happening that can abort this thread?

Code snippet:

```
public class Startup {
    public static void main(string [] args) {
        MySingletonClass.Instance.Init();
       // do other things below
       Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }

public class MySingletonClass {
// singleton code
//..
//..

private Thread t;  
public void Init() {
    t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(poll));
    t.Start();
}

private void poll() {
    while(true} {
        // listen for messages and process but there is no break clause
        // exceptions are also handled within to ensure control doesnt go out
    }
}
```

Pls. don't write to tell me this is bad code. I know it and i was going to refactor it when i realised that the app actually shutdowns correctly inspite of this aberration. 
So i want to understand how this is possible.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to clarify the question: are you saying that, for some unknown reason, your spawned thread is exiting when the app exits, and you want to know why that might be happening?

Comment: Yes, i cant figure out how a foreground thread can terminate when the app is aborted (there is no logic in the code that aborts it)

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of managed Threads that can be created by the `System.Threading.Thread` class:  [Foreground and Background Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Foreground threads will keep the process running, however after all of the foreground threads have been terminated the system stops all of the background threads and stops the process.  Threads created using `System.Thread.Thread` are foreground threads by default.  You can make them background threads by using the I[sBackground propety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx):

```
t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(poll));
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

Comment: If you copied my code into a new Winforms app in Visual Studio, you'll see that when you close the form (by clicking on the X), the app continues to run. This is because Thread t above is a foreground thread. 

However, it seems to work in this particular app. Given the huge codebase of the app, it is unfeasible to post it all here. So i wonder if there was some other way to abort the thread automatically.

Comment: Do you have a problem with making your threads background threads?  Simply adding `t.IsBackground = true;` after `t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(poll));` will close your thread automatically.

Comment: I am not looking for a solution. I am looking for an explanation for a behavior that is not meant to happen (i.e. a foreground thread exits an infinite loop)

Answer (score 1):

By default, threads created with new Thread() are foreground threads.  These threads prevent your process from exiting (as heavyd mentioned).  If you simply set [Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=VS.100).aspx) to true, closing your app should terminate the background thread.

You could introduce some logic to terminate the polling process.  For example, you could add a `Stop()` method that sets a boolean flag.  Then have the `Poll()` method continually check the status of this flag.  This works if you have some sort of timeout in the polling logic to continually stop polling for messages.

```
public class MySingletonClass
{
    private bool continuePolling = true;

    public void Stop()
    {
        continuePolling = false;
    }

    public void Poll()
    {
        while (continuePolling)
        {
            // polling for messages here
        }
    }
}
```

-- EDIT --

You said you are looking for an explanation of how the application can terminate despite the worker thread's infinite loop.  There are a few ways this could occur.

1. State may change when the user closes the application, and this state may trigger an exception in the spinning thread.  An unhandled exception would cause the thread to terminate.
2. The looping thread may have been changed to a background thread somewhere else.
3. Someone may be calling [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) which forces process termination immediately.
4. A ThreadAbortException may be thrown on the worker thread.  This would terminate the thread.

Have you verified there are no exceptions being thrown on the worker thread when the process terminates?

Comment: THanks for the solution. However, I am looking for an explanation (how can a  foreground thread exits an infinite loop when the app shuts down and the user has not explicity made it break out of the loop)